# Xamarin: How do I place an image on top of another image at a specific pixel location

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, xamarin.forms, location

I have an app I need to build with Xamarin for iOS. I'm using Xamarin.Forms at the moment.

The app is a custom view of a garden that I will need to place plant markers on in the admin at a touch. I cannot find a way to composite these images in a way I can drive the display from a database and make the markers clickable.

Any help or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Use an AbsoluteLayout container if you want to place items at a specific location.  Your garden image would be the background of the layout.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you need to use [AbsoluteLayout](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/absolute-layout/)

```
var layout = new AbsoluteLayout();

var image = new Image { Source = "foo.png" };                                     
AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds (image , new Rectangle (.5, 1, .5, .1)); 
                                                   //("X, Y, Width, Height")

layout.Children.Add (bottomLabel);

Content = layout;
```

here just a sample of placing image from c#, you can customize this to your requirement